# Expand/Collapse spans?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple `<span>` which I want to make expand/collapse. I know how to make with `<tr>` and tried same way didn't work. This SharePoint auto generated code. I don't have control on it.

```
<span id="#part1">
   <table>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    ----
    ----
    <tr> <!-- 28th tr -->
    <td> </td>
    <td>
     <div>
        <span class="ms-noWrap">
            <span class="ms-imnSpan">
                <a href="#" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink">
                    <span ><img name="imnmark">
                    </span>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan">
                <a href="#"  class="ms-imnlink" >
                    <img name="imnmark">
                </a>
                <a class="ms-subtleLink" >Sri</a>
            </span>
        </span>
        (<a href="link">4/1/2015 1:45 PM</a>): NA
        <br>
        <br>
        <span class="ms-noWrap">
            <span class="ms-imnSpan">
                <a href="#" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink">
                    <span ><img name="imnmark">
                    </span>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan">
                <a href="#"  class="ms-imnlink" >
                    <img name="imnmark">
                </a>
                <a class="ms-subtleLink" >Sri</a>
            </span>
        </span>
        (<a href="link">4/1/2015 1:45 PM</a>): NA
        <br>
        <br>
            <span class="ms-noWrap"> <!-- From here I want expand /collapse -->
            <span class="ms-imnSpan">
                <a href="#" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink">
                    <span ><img name="imnmark">
                    </span>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan">
                <a href="#"  class="ms-imnlink" >
                    <img name="imnmark">
                </a>
                <a class="ms-subtleLink" >Sri</a>
            </span>
        </span>
        (<a href="link">4/1/2015 1:45 PM</a>): NA
        <br>
        <br>    
    <div>
    </span>
   <td>
<tr>
```

I tried

```
    <script src="/dept/it/Shared%20Documents/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                  var commentrow="<tr class='comment expand'><td nowrap='true' valign='top' width='113px' class='ms-formlabel'><h4 class='ms-standardheader'><u> More comments..<u></h4></td><td valign='top' class='ms-formbody' width='350px' ></td></tr>";   
                  $(commentrow).insertAfter("#part1 table tr:nth-child(28) td:nth-child(2) div span:nth-child(4)")
        $('.comment').toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.comment').slideToggle(10);
                   $('.comment').click(function(){           

              $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.comment').slideToggle(100);
        });
       });
</script>
<style>
    tr.comment
    {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial span has id `#part1`, and you're trying to reference it using the same value. But this will not work in jQuery since # is a notation **for** id. Instead you'll have to escape the hash:

```
$(commentrow).insertAfter("#\\#part1 table ... etc.
```

While I'm at it, you're also trying to add a `tr` before ending a current. The `commentrow` should probably start with:

```
var commentrow="</tr><tr class=" ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Making rows hide show can be trickier than divs or spans because of their quirky display properties, tied to table structure.  I did put together this jquery demo that may do what you want:

[jsfiddle - click to hide/show rows](https://jsfiddle.net/pianopaul/breymdem/110/)

```js
// Basically, hide all comments except direct child comment, then toggle child.

$('.expand').hide();
$('.hasComment').click(function(){
    var com = $(this).next('.comment');
     $('.comment').not(com).hide();
    com.toggleClass('expand').slideToggle(600);        
});
```